# bs-platform version mismatch

Tags: yarnpkg, reason, bucklescript

I have a global `bs-platform` installation and a local one for a local project. They are in different versions. Everything was fine until today. Every time I try to run my local project, the following error is thrown:

```
bs-platform version mismatch Running bsb 5.0.4 (/home/jefferson/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/bs-platform) vs vendored 4.0.5 (/home/jefferson/astrocoders/lion-carne-client/node_modules/bs-platform)
```

How can this be solved? I'm using `yarn`.

Comment: How are you running bsb? Via a script?

Comment: No, I'm running it directly through `yarn` (`yarn bsb -make-world`)

Comment: When you run like this yarns ends indeed picking the global one for some Reason, what I do to fix this is to add to "scripts" in my package.json a "bs:build": "yarn bsb -make-world", so running yarn bs:build instead will make yarn pick the right binary

Comment: I also do something similar to @fakenickels, in my case I run commands prefixed with `npx`, so `npx bsb` to make sure that the project's version of BuckleScript is the one that gets used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use the locally installed package

   a. Through a script defined in `package.json`, executed using `yarn run` or `npm run`

   b. Through executing the command via `npx`, which comes with `npm`: `npx bsb -make-world`
2. Use the globally installed package by linking it into the project and overwriting any locally installed package of the same name, using either `yarn link bs-platform` or `npm link bs-platform` (only needed once per project). `node_modules/bs-platform` will then be a symlink that points to the globally installed package, hence no version mismatch when running the global `bsb`.